# How do I properly structure a dark mode toggle using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, toggle, darkmode

I've been trying to have my toggle trigger a dark mode on and off using JavaScript but clearly I'm doing something wrong. I attempted to trigger it by applying the light class to my body and using addClassListener. Below is a simplified version of my code but i also plan on doing this on specific classes as well in order to change font and div colors in each different mode as well. Any suggestions?

HTML

```
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span id="slide" class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

CSS

```
body{
          
          position: absolute;
          top: 320px;
          left: 0;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          background-color: hsl(230, 17%, 14%);
          z-index: -1;
          
          
      }
    
    body.light {
          
          background-color: white;
          
          
      }
```

Javascript

```
const checkbox = document.getElementById('slide');
        
        checkbox.addEventListener('change', ()
                                 ==>{document.body.classList.toggle('light');
            
        });
```

Comment: As you can see I’m still new to the language. That was supposed to be =>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to get the element by `id`, but you have not defined any `id`s in your snippet.

```
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span id="slider" class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

Additionally, you're listening for a `change` event on a `span` element. The `span` element will never fire a change event.  If you change that to listen in the `input` element, it should fire. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)